# If composite transparent materials thermal and electrical conductivity can be adjusted t what would be benefit?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, power-electronics, solar-cell, optoelectronics

Will it be provided less thermal and electrical gradient to support less dissipative system development for opto-electronics and related technologies?

For thermoelectric design how it cold be benefitted?

Comment: is this homework?
Also you haven't explained how optoelectronics is related to this

Comment: How electrical conductivity can be increased by decreasing thermal conduction?